# SQLite Database Memory Space

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, cordova, memory

I'm using SQLite with phonegap/cordova on iOS and I'm wondering how I know how much space to give a database. Right now this is set up to take 2MB but I'm wondering if that's enough. What happens if you fill it up? How can I know how much space I'm taking up?

```
db = window.openDatabase('Database', '1.0', 'NameOfDB', 2097152);
```

Comment: Please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061357/size-of-memory-allocated-to-a-sqlite-in-memory-database), which discusses something similar to your question.

Comment: The amount of memory you need will be a function of many things, including how many users you expect and how much memory each statement a given user will take up.